# how to pass argument to autoIT script from python script

Tags: python, autoit

In my python scripting, I need to pass the command line arguments to AutoIt script. Because in my AutoIt script I am getting command line arguments and processing it. The below AutoIt script I am using to get command line arguments and it is working fine:

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <WinAPIShPath.au3>
Local $aCmdLine = _WinAPI_CommandLineToArgv($CmdLineRaw)
_ArrayDisplay($aCmdLine)
```

Now using my python script i need to pass the command line arguments to the above autoIt script.

I tried using in a Python script:

```
import os
args = ("test","abc")
os.execv("test.au3",args)
```

but it is giving an exception.

Comment: Exception type and message would tell you exactly what is a problem. Why have you omitted it in question?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

**In your AutoIT script, put this piece of code in**

AutoIT's variable $CMDLINE contains the parameters provided. And the variable $PAR (feel free to change its name) will be storing the parameter for later use.

```
$PAR = ''
If $CmdLine[0] > 0 Then
If $CmdLine[1] <> @ScriptName Then
    $PAR = $CmdLine[1] ;Now, you can use the variable $PAR in your script.

            Endif
Endif
```

**Put this in your Python script**

**parameter** will be the parameter you want to pass

```
os.system("location/to/autoit/file.exe "+parameter )
```

I hope that fixed your issue.